# asp.net - LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Char get_Chars(Int32)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm new to ASP.NET MVC4 and Entity Framework.

I set up a new method in my API which is supposed to get all `partners` that have a `prestation` with a name found in GET parameter `prestation`.

I'm getting the error in the title and don't know how to fix it:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Char get_Chars(Int32)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Here's my method:

```
// GET: api/Partenaires_prestations
[Authorize]
[Route("api/Partenaires_prestations")]
public List<PartenaireMapItem> GetPartenairesWithPrestations()
{
    Random rnd = new Random();

    var queryString = Request.GetQueryNameValuePairs();

    var prestation = queryString.FirstOrDefault();

    return db.Partenaires
        .Where(p => p.PartenairePrestations.Any(pp => pp.Prestation.NomPrestation == prestation.Value))
        .Select(p => new PartenaireMapItem
        {
            IdPartenaire = p.IdPartenaire,
            FirstName = p.FirstName,
            LastName = p.LastName,
            NomComplet = p.LastName.ToUpper()[0] + ". " + p.FirstName,
            Type = p.Type,
            DureeMin = rnd.Next(2, 50),
            Lat = p.Lat,
            Lng = p.Lng,
            ImageUrl = p.ImageUrl,
            SeDeplace = p.SeDeplace,
            ADomicile = p.ADomicile,

            NoteGlobale = rnd.Next(1, 6),
            Prestations = new List<string>(p.PartenairePrestations.Select(y => y.Prestation.NomPrestation))
        }).ToList();
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks to anyone who will take the time to read/answer this post.

Comment: `p.LastName.ToUpper()[0] ` does not translate to proper sql statement. That's why you are seeing this error ?

Comment: @MustaphaLarhrouch I didn't...

Comment: Building on the comment by Chetan, instead of indexing your string possibly try using `p.LastName.Substring(0, 1).ToUpper()`

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya It's worhking in another method that existed before... What could I do to fix this ?

Comment: The string indexer property is named [`Chars`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.chars(v=vs.110).aspx), but you don't ever see that name in C# code. It's the part that Chetan Ranpariya pointed out.

Comment: Same error using p.LastName.Substring(0, 1)

Comment: @PierrickMartellière If you're still getting an error about `get_Chars` when you've taken out the only string indexing you've shown in your code, then you're not showing the relevant code.

Comment: What code part should I show instead ? This is the method that is called, could it come from QueryString parameters ?

Comment: @PierrickMartellière I suspect either you never actually changed the code as hinted (perhaps you did but forgot to re-build your project, so you're still using your old code), or you didn't notice that although you still get an exception, the exception message changed. But to get *that* particular exception message after changing the code as indicated should not be possible. It cannot come from the query string parameters. It could come from some other code called by your method, but I'm not seeing where you're calling any other code that could cause this.

Comment: Yup, my bad, edited the method up this one that is near from the same. Sorry for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write a LINQ query using Entity Framework it attempts to translate your query into a SQL query.  Some .NET operations cannot be translated into SQL.  I believe the offending line is:

```
p.LastName.ToUpper()[0]
```

I also expect that your calls to rnd.Next() will cause errors too.

Here is how I would handle this scenario:

1. Execute the query without the offending columns.  End your query with .ToList().  This will load the result set into memory.
2. Loop through the result set and add the missing columns.  Since your result set is already loaded into memory it will not throw errors on .NET operations.

```
    var result = db.Partenaires
        .Where(p => p.PartenairePrestations.Any(pp => pp.Prestation.NomPrestation == prestation.Value))
        .Select(p => new PartenaireMapItem {
            IdPartenaire = p.IdPartenaire,
            FirstName = p.FirstName,
            LastName = p.LastName,
            Type = p.Type,
            Lat = p.Lat,
            Lng = p.Lng,
            ImageUrl = p.ImageUrl,
            SeDeplace = p.SeDeplace,
            ADomicile = p.ADomicile,
            Prestations = new List(p.PartenairePrestations.Select(y => y.Prestation.NomPrestation))
        }).ToList();

    foreach (var row in result) {
        row.NomComplet = row.LastName.ToUpper()[0] + ". " + row.FirstName;
        row.DureeMin = rnd.Next(2, 50);
        row.NoteGlobale = rnd.Next(1, 6);
    }

    return result;
```

A second approach would be to create a stored procedure in SQL Server.  This would eliminate the need to split up the query.  This is the most efficient approach, but also takes more work, and it adds more layers to your application.  I would only recommend this option if you expect a high volume of traffic and data.

Note:  A third approach would be to avoid the error by using .AsEnumerable() or .ToList() immediately after db.Partenaires.  For example:

`db.Partenaires.AsEnumerable().Where`... or `db.Partenaires.ToList().Where`...

However, the danger to this method is that **it loads the entire table into memory**.  In other words, the SQL query will be equivalent to `select * from Partenaires`.  Then Entity Framework will have to perform additional queries to retrieve data in related tables (like PartenairePrestations) and it will perform all of the other filtering and operations in-memory.  This is the **least efficient** option.  Although this approach will work short-term it will start to become a performance issue as your data grows, so I don't recommend it.

Comment: Great answer ! Ty.